# How do I have VBA sort the same way the excel sort works largest to smallest?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, inputbox

I'm new to VBA but making some progress using the site.  I am trying to get excel to sort a list of quarterly numbers that shows the last 10 quarters of revenue starting with xQyr AMT in the top(x is 1-4).  I have this working with an input from the user and then it sorts the data in descending order.  What I would like is to be able to filter all the columns with the selected column sorting but the other columns not losing their order respectively.  Any help is apprecaited!!

Also, any tips for a new coder would be welcomed!

```
'i = total number of rows(for deleting front text only)
'strpt = First Cell with values(Top Line)
'lastcol = total columns with values
'lastrow = total rows after top is removed
'flt = interested column to filter
'range1 = first cell to sort
'fstcell = first cell to sort
'look = input variable to look for


Sub filterq()
    Dim totloc As Long, lastcol As Integer, lastrow As Integer, look As String
    strtpt = 0
    AutoFilterMode = False 'Set AutoFilter off
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Determine First Cell with information
    strpt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("*", Range("B1:B" & i), 0)
    MsgBox strpt
    'Delete top portions
    'Range("A1:A" & strpt - 1).EntireRow.Delete

    'Determine Number of Columns & Rows in the sheet
    lastcol = Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox lastrow & " " & lastcol

    'Delete "Total" Row
    'Find in Column A, Row with Total in text
    'totloc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Total", Range("A1:A" & lastrow), 0)
    'MsgBox totloc
    'Range("A" & totloc).EntireRow.Delete

    'Filter columns to show highest revenue
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastcol)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    look = Application.InputBox("Enter Quarter:", Type:=2)
    look = look + " AMT"
    MsgBox look
    flt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(look, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastcol)), 0) 'Search for cell to filter
    MsgBox flt

    Set range1 = Range(Cells(1, flt), Cells(lastrow, flt))
    Set fstcell = Cells(2, flt)

    range1.Sort Key1:=fstcell, Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I needed to change the range to the entire table and then fstcell to the key column to be filtered.